# How to give multiple routes in route.config file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-5

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Letter",
            url: "{Home}/{Letter}/{ListId}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Letter", ListId=1}                               
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "words",
            url: "{Home}/{words}/{WListId}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "words", WListId ="w1" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id=     UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

**cshtml:**

```
@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")
@Html.ActionLink("Letter", "Letter/1", "Home")
@Html.ActionLink("Words", "words/w1", "Home")
```

I am doing this in `route.config` and `.cshtml` respectively but every time it redirects me to the letter page even when i click on "words" or "home".  When I click words or home it changes the url but does not  change the view.  Can any one suggest how to give multiples route in route.config file?  What's wrong with this code ?

Comment: Because you first route matches all values you enter (you may as well delete the first 2). If you want a specific route for `Letter` where you method is `public ActionResult Letter(int ListId)` then it needs to be `url: "Home/Letter/{ListId}",` - no `{` and `}` around the controller and action - and then its `@Html.ActionLink("Letter", "Letter", "Home", new { ListId = 1 }, null)`

Answer (score 1):

I'm completely revamping this because I think I now see what you are trying to do.

An `ActionLink` works as a helper to render an anchor element. So using

```
@Html.ActionLink("Link", "Action", "Controller")
```

helper, your page renders something in the form of:

```
<a href="/Controller/Action">Link</a>
```

What you want then, is to write the proper controller and action values - you don't need routes for this. So in order to produce a link for `Home/words/1`, you can use the `ActionLink`  helper (with the default route only) like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Words", "Words", "Home", new { WListId = "w1" })
```

This will produce:

```
/Home/Words/w1
```

and in your `HomeController.cs`, your action must look like:

```
public ActionResult Words(string WListId)
{
    // whatever you want to do with WListId

    return View();
}
```

and your View must be named `Words.cshtml`

The same goes for Letter as well. For this, all you need is the one Default Route that's already there.

```
routes.MapRoute(
      name: "Default",
      url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
      defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id=UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Comment: its not working ..  still showing the same view on  every page . and i have to redrect on a particular id of words i.e words/w1.

Comment: Ok, I think I got what you were asking and changed the answer. Try this.

Comment: A few errors here - it needs to be `@Html.ActionLink("Words", "Words", "Home", new { WListId = "w1" }, null)` and it wont produce `/Home/Words/w1` - it will produce `/Home/Words?WListId=w1` unless you add a specific route with `.../{WListId}` (or change the method to `public ActionResult Words(string id)`